# Cannot open .lib file when switch to Intel C++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I used to use Visual C++ compiler in visual studio 2019, it works well.Now I heard that the Intel compiler can automatically parallelize the code, so I want to try it, however, under Intel compiler, there is a building error, namely, a .lib file cannot file. Any suggestion to handle this?

The message is cannot find library CGAL-iw-mt-4.10.2.lib from #pragma comment

But I don't think I code something like `pragma comment(xxx.lib)`

Comment: Even if it could find the file, you can't share `.lib` files across different compilers

Comment: thank you Remy, so what should I do to use intel compiler?